# NTFS-3G unmounts USB drive as soon as it is mounted

Tags: linux, mount, ntfs, udev, systemd

I have created an udev rule to automount a USB hard-disk when I plug it in, but the drive doesn't appear as mounted. In /var/log/messages, I can see

```
Dec 27 09:11:02 smug ntfs-3g[6043]: Version 2014.2.15 integrated FUSE 27
Dec 27 09:11:02 smug ntfs-3g[6043]: Mounted /dev/sdb1 (Read-Write, label "Seagate Expansion Drive", NTFS 3.1)
Dec 27 09:11:02 smug ntfs-3g[6043]: Cmdline options: rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,users
Dec 27 09:11:02 smug ntfs-3g[6043]: Mount options: rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,users,allow_other,nonempty,relatime,fsname=/dev/sdb1,blkdev,blksize=4096
Dec 27 09:11:02 smug ntfs-3g[6043]: Ownership and permissions disabled, configuration type 1
Dec 27 09:11:02 smug ntfs-3g[6043]: Unmounting /dev/sdb1 (Seagate Expansion Drive)
Dec 27 09:11:03 smug ntfs-3g[6051]: Version 2014.2.15 integrated FUSE 27
Dec 27 09:11:03 smug ntfs-3g[6051]: Mounted /dev/sdb1 (Read-Write, label "Seagate Expansion Drive", NTFS 3.1)
Dec 27 09:11:03 smug ntfs-3g[6051]: Cmdline options: rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,users
Dec 27 09:11:03 smug ntfs-3g[6051]: Mount options: rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,users,allow_other,nonempty,relatime,fsname=/dev/sdb1,blkdev,blksize=4096
Dec 27 09:11:03 smug ntfs-3g[6051]: Ownership and permissions disabled, configuration type 1
Dec 27 09:11:03 smug ntfs-3g[6051]: Unmounting /dev/sdb1 (Seagate Expansion Drive)
```

and I don't understand why it is unmounted as soon as it is mounted, and twice: it must be a systemd-udevd quirk, but I didn't find anything relevant in the manpages.

Any help welcome, thanks!